# SimpleDB: Select Rows With One Of Top 5 Most Common Values

Tags: sql, amazon-simpledb

I'm using the Amazon Web Services API to interact with a SimpleDB domain.  The relevant code is

```
selectExpression = "SELECT * FROM myDomain";

selectRequestAction = new SelectRequest().WithSelectExpression(selectExpression)
                                         .WithNextToken(nextToken);
selectResponse = sdb.Select(selectRequestAction);
```

At this point I iterate through each returned line and do funky stuff.  My table looks like this:

```
|  Name  |  AAA  | BBB | CCC  |
-------------------------------
| 519515 |  fox  | 311 | 1111 |
| 216165 |  cbs  | 971 | 1112 |
| 618105 |  nbc  | 035 | 1113 |
| 187655 |  npr  | 851 | 1114 |
| 551973 |  npr  | 654 | 1115 |
| 018583 |  cbs  | 302 | 1116 |
| 284801 |  www  | 762 | 1117 |
```

Basically I want to return all rows where AAA one of the top 5 AAA's.  For instance, if there are:

- 1000 rows where AAA is 'cbs'
- 800 where AAA is 'elo'
- 400 where AAA is 'npr'
- 304 where AAA is 'www'
- 200 where AAA is 'fox'

and

- 100 where AAA is 'qwe'

I would like to return all rows where AAA is 'cbs', 'elo', 'npr', 'www', or 'fox'.

Thanks!

Comment: Deleted my answer. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Can you please add a sample of your desire output from your above table? Can you add output table?

Answer (score 0):

What I am understand from your question, you need following output-

```
|  AAA  | 
---------
|  fox  |
|  cbs  |
|  elo  |
|  www  |
|  npr  |
```

for that you have to individually run these query-

```
select * from `myDomain` where `AAA` = 'cbs' order by `AAA` asc limit 1
select * from `myDomain` where `AAA` = 'fox' order by `AAA` asc limit 1
select * from `myDomain` where `AAA` = 'elo' order by `AAA` asc limit 1
select * from `myDomain` where `AAA` = 'www' order by `AAA` asc limit 1
select * from `myDomain` where `AAA` = 'npr' order by `AAA` asc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your top 5 values for the AAA attribute, you can use this query

```
select * from `myDomain` where `AAA` in('cbs','fox','elo', 'www', 'npr')
```

This will return all the rows where AAA is 'cbs', 'elo', 'npr', 'www', or 'fox'.